# Tool to upgrade current python installation

Tags: apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, ampps

I have Python 2.7 installed with [ampps](/questions/tagged/ampps). I tried to modify python.conf to make it point to another installation of Python 3.3 but it leads to errors in Apache start up.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Python33/Lib;C:/Python33/Lib/site-packages;C:/Python33/DLLs"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python33"
```

It generates the following error:

```
[Fri Aug 15 01:48:38.114336 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6084:tid 412] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5592
  File "C:/Python33\lib\site.py", line 173
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Fri Aug 15 01:48:39.146395 2014] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 6084:tid 412] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```