# Apache24-x86-VC9 with mod_wsgi says, "AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting." and won't start

Tags: python, x86, mod-wsgi, visual-c++-2008

I am trying to install WSGI capability on my Windows version of Apache24. When I try to start the service I get the following in my error.log:

> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:33.404057 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2960:tid 728] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:33.544690 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2960:tid 728] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:33.544690 2015] [wsgi:warn] [pid 2960:tid 728] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.10+.
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:33.544690 2015] [wsgi:warn] [pid 2960:tid 728] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.11.
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:33.544690 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2960:tid 728] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e mod_wsgi/4.4.21 Python/2.7.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:33.544690 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2960:tid 728] AH00456: Server built: Dec  9 2015 12:21:09
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:33.544690 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2960:tid 728] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\apache24\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:33.544690 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2960:tid 728] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3112
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:34.091593 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3112:tid 656] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:34.216600 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3112:tid 656] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:34.216600 2015] [wsgi:warn] [pid 3112:tid 656] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.10+.
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:34.216600 2015] [wsgi:warn] [pid 3112:tid 656] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.11.
>       ImportError: No module named site
>
> [Wed Dec 23 10:24:34.216600 2015] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 2960:tid 728] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.

It is the error AH00419 that I cannot figure out after DAYS of research.

So, let’s back up. These are the steps I took previous to getting this error:

I copied the  mod_wsgi.so  file out of the  mod_wsgi-4.4.21+ap24vc9-cp27-none-win32.whl  archive using WinRAR.

I copied it into my c:\Apache24\modules directory

I added this line to my httpd.conf file:  "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so"

My Python27 is 32-bit

My Apache24 is 32-bit and is the VC9 version

I have installed Visual C++ 2008 (VC9) 32-bit

Apache24 starts up just fine if I comment out that "LoadModule... ...wsgi" line.

I can't be the only one that has run into this problem but I have been unable to find a solution online. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether you have found the answer already since the question is more than two months old. Anyway I faced exact same issue. I used following combination of software.

Apace 2.4 VC9 32bit from https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx#APACHE24VC09
mod_wsgi for Python 2.7 32bit from http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=5143

After apache installation and loading the wsgi module I got the following error.

> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:57.641443 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 13892:tid 340] AH01909: localhost:600:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:57.811445 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 13892:tid 340] AH01909: localhost:600:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:57.811445 2016] [:warn] [pid 13892:tid 340] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:57.811445 2016] [:warn] [pid 13892:tid 340] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.11.
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:57.811445 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13892:tid 340] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2f mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:57.811445 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13892:tid 340] AH00456: Server built: Dec  9 2015 12:21:09
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:57.811445 2016] [core:notice] [pid 13892:tid 340] AH00094: Command line: 'Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -d E:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache24'
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:57.821445 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13892:tid 340] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 13684
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:58.271449 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 13684:tid 352] AH01909: localhost:600:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:58.421451 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 13684:tid 352] AH01909: localhost:600:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:58.421451 2016] [:warn] [pid 13684:tid 352] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:58.421451 2016] [:warn] [pid 13684:tid 352] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.11.
>   ImportError: No module named site
>
> [Thu Mar 03 13:51:58.431451 2016] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 13892:tid 340] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.

After that I ran "netsh winsock RESET" which was stated as a solution in some other forum but didn't restart the computer though it prompted me to do so. But it didn't make any change in the situation.

Then I found following question here which gave me a clue that I might be missing some configuration.

[Tool to upgrade current python installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318819/tool-to-upgrade-current-python-installation)

I added following lines to my httpd.conf

> WSGIPythonPath "C:/Python33/Lib;C:/Python33/Lib/site-packages;C:/Python33/DLLs"
>   WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python33"

Then Apache started to work fine.

Comment: Awesome!!! PS In my case I just needed to set Python path to my virtual environment (no lib nor dlls folder): `WSGIPythonPath /path/to/my/venv`. The key here is the `WSGIPythonHome` which is wrongly reported as not supported for Windows systems ([link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ConfigurationDirectives.wiki)).